# Who are the villains that Spider-Man fights in his self-introduction scene in Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, spider-man, spider-man-across-the-spider-verse

In *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse*, we see Miles Morales / Spider-Man fighting several villains in his self-introduction scene:

1. A villain with a white mask and a green costume with a four-leaf clover pattern
   [image] [image]
2. A bearded villain with a brass knuckle, prohibition-era gangster clothing, and a fedora
   [image]
3. A villain in a frog costume; likely Leap-Frog
   [image]
4. A hooded villain with sunglasses and a purple costume
   [image]
5. A villain in a bearskin costume; likely Kraven the Hunter
   [image]
6. A robot or a person in a bulky armored suit
   [image] [image]

While I recognize characters #3 and #5 (please correct me if I'm mistaken), the identities of the other villains elude me.

##### Who are the villains that Spider-Man (Miles Morales) fights in his self-introduction scene in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse*?

(To clarify, I am only asking about the villains that Miles Morales fights in his self-introduction scene, not the villains that the other Spider-Man variants fight in their self-introduction scenes.)

Comment: I'd suspect #5 to be [Grizzly III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grizzly_(comics)).

Comment: #2 might be [Hammerhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammerhead_(comics)) although he's usually Caucasian.

Comment: I actually mistook the #5 with [M'Baku/Man-Ape from Avengers: EMH](https://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120629045357/avengersearthsmightiestheroes/images/5/54/Man_Ape.png)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots There's not really a lot of skin showing but #2 looks pretty White to me.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-L The beard may have thrown me off, appearing to be brown skin to me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I managed to ID the characters with the aid of [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/sA8sMNJnAaE?t=790) showcasing concept art from *[Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse: The Art of the Film](https://www.marvel.com/articles/culture-lifestyle/spider-man-across-the-spider-verse-the-art-of-the-film-on-sale-now)*.

1. **[The Chameleon](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dmitri_Smerdyakov_(Earth-1610B))** (Earth-1610B)

> [image: Concept art of The Chameleon by Mauro Belfiore.]
>
> <sub>[Concept art by Mauro Belfiore](https://www.instagram.com/p/CuXCngnN2jv/?img_index=1)</sub>

2. **[Hammerhead](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Hammerhead_(Joseph)_(Earth-1610B))** (Earth-1610B)

> [image: Concept art of Hammerhead by Will Coyner.]
>
> <sub>[Concept art by Will Coyner](https://twitter.com/willcoyner/status/1674883564889079808)</sub>

3. **[Frog-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eugene_Patilio_(Earth-1610B))** (Earth-1610B)

> [image: Concept art of Frog-Man by Mauro Belfiore.]
>
> <sub>[Concept art by Mauro Belfiore](https://64.media.tumblr.com/87e6b52386ae5e2c56645a913c351e67/587d975ae362af40-ae/s2048x3072/675f8a9759ba0128ee68d239925d0659e3f1604e.jpg)</sub>

4. **[The Beetle](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Abner_Jenkins_(Earth-1610B))** (Earth-1610B)

> [image: Concept art of the Beetle by Kristafer Anka.]
>
> <sub>[Concept art by Kristafer Anka](https://twitter.com/kristaferanka/status/1683502392757862401)</sub>

5. **[The Grizzly](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Maxwell_Markham_(Earth-1610B))** (Earth-1610B)

> [image: Concept art of the Grizzly by Jesus Alonso Iglesias.]
>
> <sub>[Concept art by Jesus Alonso Iglesias](https://twitter.com/hombreoctubre/status/1682750653246984192)</sub>

6. A **[Spider-Slayer](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Slayer_(Earth-1610B))** robot (Earth-1610B)

> [image: Concept art of Spider-Slayer by Mauro Belfiore.]
>
> <sub>[Concept art by Mauro Belfiore](https://www.instagram.com/p/Ct1qODztBbT/?img_index=1)</sub>

Comment: A fantastic answer. Did you just happen to know this, or did someone already do the legwork on these?

Comment: I guessed who the last four were likely to be, but didn't know any of them for sure. The YouTube video of the artbook (linked beneath Hammerhead's image) was the key to pinning everything down. It didn't name the characters, but it named the artists who drew their concept designs for the movie, and googling the artists enabled me to positively ID five of the six characters. Hammerhead was the exception, so in his case I just used a screencap of his concept art from the artbook. It doesn't outright state his name, but the annotations make it fairly obvious who he is.

Comment: 3, 5 and 6 look pretty similar to their classic comicbook designs, so I guessed who they were likely to be. 1, 2 and 4 look very different to the comicbook versions, but 4 reminded me of the Insecticon, [Shrapnel](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Shrapnel_(G1)), oddly enough, which in turn led me to suspect that he could be a redesign of the Beetle. I never would've guessed who 1 and 2 were without seeing the artbook.

Comment: I found a source directly naming Hammerhead, and have now edited the answer to include that.